# Timer in sqlite?

Tags: android, timer

I have a timer in one of the activity in my app,I want it to continue running regardless whether I am still in that activity or moved to another activity before going back in a little while. I believe this need to save the timer in the database,right?may I know how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

> - ***a*** = currentRunningTimeLeft (inMillis) = time in your timer,
> - ***b*** = currentTime1 (inMillis) = System.currentTimeMillis() when you leave the activity,
> - ***c*** = currentTime2 (inMillis) = System.currentTimeMillis() current real time,
> - ***d*** = timeReduced = time that will reduce currentTime3,
> - ***e*** = currentTime3 (inMillis) = time you will get when reopen the activity

onPause -> Save ***a*** and ***b*** to your database in Long

onResume -> ***d*** = (***c*** - ***b***) ,then ***e*** = (***a*** - ***d***), and use "***e***" in your timer

*#cmiiw*

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's very wrong.

An SQlite database is simply a database for storing data. You can store the current tick values of your Timer, or other data related to your timer, but it can't be used to allow your Timer to continue running.

There's simply no function in an SQlite database that will allow a timer to continue running.

Instead, you should look into using the Timer in a Foreground Service. This way, users can switch from Activity to Activity, even to other apps and your timer will still be running.

Comment: I have never come across this term before,would you kindly help me out?

Comment: A Foreground Service is simply a Service that you run in a foreground. There's ways to run a Service: Background, Foreground, Bound. Background Services have restrictions in recent Android versions that cause them to only have a few minutes of 'active' time, amongst other restrictions. Since you didn't mention how long your timer runs, it's possible it might require more time than allocated for background services.

Comment: Bound services are attached to an Application Component, like an Activity, but this causes them to live as long as the bounded Activity lives. So if you switch away to another Activity, the Service might end up dying if the system kills the Activity in some way or another. The Foreground Service works best for your timer scenario, since it allows it to run for any amount of time. Here's a link to turning your Service into a Foreground Service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground

Comment: Will this work even if other users(devices) try accessing it lets say,it started at 10 mins.and countdown to 4 minutes before a new user comes into that activity.will it show 4 mins remaining ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by another device entering into the Activity of your device.

Comment: My app is actually an online auction where users can go in and out of that activity to bid and comment.but there's a timer which will disable all biddings after it times out.so I need the timer to continue even though he/she leaves for a moment.

Comment: If it's that scenario, then there's really no need for a local Timer that continues running outside of your Activity. I assume that your server posseses a value for the ending time of the item. It's more efficient to query for the ending time of the item when the Activity opens up for that item. Then you can do your Timer to show the user how much time is left. If they leave the Activity, then there's no need to show a running Timer anymore. When they go back to the Activity, you'll simply start up another timer using the same queried ending time to show them how much time is left.

Comment: Basically, there's no need to have an ongoing timer for your scenario because it's not necessary. If they view 10 different auction items, were you planning to have 10 different timers running in the background? What if they browsed 50 items? That's a very inefficient use of resources and very battery draining too. Instead, my suggestion is to simply show a timer only when they're in that Activity of the item. If you want to notify them that an item is ending soon, you can just schedule an alarm through `JobScheduler`, `AlarmManager` or other such services.

Comment: So you're saying I make use of the local time in it for my timing issues?

Comment: If you look at other Auction apps, none of them are actually running a Timer after you leave the item. The Timer you see is actually only ticking when you're viewing the item. It doesn't continue ticking after you've left, otherwise, your phone will get extremely slow after browsing a lot of items in the auction. Instead, the timer is simply a visual representation of the ending time, which is shown only when you're currently browsing the item.

Comment: So how do I go about doing this ?you're saying it does not run in the background,instead it will update the time when the user enters into the auction again?

Comment: When you start your Activity that shows an item, you should fetch the time the Auction ends. With this ending time and the current time, that's already enough information for you to create a CountDown from the current time to the ending time. You simply have to display that Count Down to the user. There's no need to have an ongoing timer after the user exits the item's activity, because your Activity will always be showing the correct remaining time every time it starts. This is due to knowing the ending time and the current time, to calculate a Count Down from this info.